# Why do I receive FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sbin/iwlist'

Tags: python-3.5

Using the following Python code:

```
>>> from wifi import Cell, Scheme
>>> Cell.all('wlan0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wifi/scan.py", line 39, in all
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
File"/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 629, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 696, in run
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1540, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sbin/iwlist'
```

Why am I getting the error message `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sbin/iwlist'?`

Answer (score 1):

The Python module you're trying to use only works on Linux -- the "iwlist" executable is Linux-specific. The module is incompatible with macOS -- you will need to find a Python module which supports macOS, or use this module on a Linux computer. (A virtual machine will *not* work, as it won't have access to your machine's wireless hardware.)

Answer (score 1):

Need to reinstall the wireless-tool, so yo get iwconfig

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall wireless-tools
```

Comment: I had the original OP Error trying to work with the wifi adapter in a raspberry pi with python and this was my problem.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You either do not have installed `iwlist` or it is installed on different path, for example `/usr/sbin/iwlist`. If that is the case then you can create a symbolink link, ex.:

`ln -s /usr/sbin/iwlist /sbin/iwlist'

If it is not installed, well then you need to install it.

Comment: You're missing a very important detail -- the author is using Mac OS, and iwlist is a Linux wireless tool.